# Jena3 Java Upload model to Virtuoso

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jena, virtuoso

I am making a Java service based on Jena3, in order to store a new Model into Virtuoso. I am using <strike>Java3</strike> Jena 3, with the following Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to make store the following model (just an example), using the following code:

```
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

VirtModel virtualModel = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(VIRTUOSO_GRAPH, VIRTUOSO_URL, VIRTUOSO_USERNAME, VIRTUOSO_PASSWORD);
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.createResource("http://example.com/my#resource");
//Add model
virtualModel.add(model);
```

However, it seems class `VirtModel` is not recognized. I cannot `import virtuoso.jena.driver.*;`.

I tried to put different maven dependencies for Virtuoso JDBC (found on different githubs with examples) but it is not working.

I think this have to be retrieved from https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource but I do not know how can I do this.

Anyone experiencing the same issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: get the files here: http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload#For%20Jena%203.0.x%20and%20later and include them in your project

Comment: It worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- I think you are using *Jena* 3 (not *Java* 3)…
- The [Virtuoso Jena documentation](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider) is likely to be helpful.  The specific components you need (JDBC Driver, Jena Provider for Jena 3) are [downloadable here](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload#For%20Jena%203.0.x%20and%20later) and should then be included in your project.
- There is [an open issue for adding these components to the Maven Central Repository](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/589) to which you could add your voice.